# convert .txt file to array and display via select stament

Tags: php, file-handling

I need to convert a text file to an array and display each line of the array in a select statement.  For some reason I can only get the select statement to display the line numbers in the .txt file and not the content of each line.

```
<select name="course">
     <option value="">              </option>
     <?php
          $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('courses.txt'));
          foreach($lines as $courses => $value):
          echo '<option value="'.$courses.'">'.$courses.'</option>';
          endforeach;
     ?>
</select>
```

I have searched on a couple different sites and this appears to be the best way to convert a file to an array `$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('courses.txt'));` so I assume that this is correct.

Comment: What is `$value`? I think `$course` is the the index of the file.

Comment: [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Reads entire file into an array

Comment: Simply doing an explode like that will give you a numerical array with each line as the values. You are looping over with a foreach loop like `foreach($lines as $key=>$value)`. Then you are using the key in the option which will be a number, not the text of the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the value inside the option to be `$value` instead of `$course`. You can leave `$course` as the value of the option because then you know which index in the file they choose when they submitted the form.

```
 <select name="course">
 <option value="">              </option>
 <?php
 $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('courses.txt'));
 foreach($lines as $courses => $value): ?>
      <option value="<?= $courses ?>"><?= $value ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('courses.txt'));` no need to recreate file()

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability:

```
 <select name="course">
     <?php
     $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('courses.txt'));
     foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
          echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
     }; ?>
 </select>
```

I would also recommend doing all the business logic in the controller and passing the array to the view to populate the drop down; but that may be out of the scope of requirements for this issue.